# What's rabbitmqctl password?

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

I have install rabbitmq 3.6.10 on centos7. When I want to do something with `rabbitmqctl` ,it ask me the password. I have tried su password or the `guest` which as raddbitmq default password,but it appeard `su: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session` .Is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`rabbitmqctl` has not a password, it asks the `sudo` password.

The problem: `Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session` is not related to RabbitMQ but you have another kind of the problem.

There are several posts, check for example this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152098/what-does-cannot-make-remove-an-entry-for-the-specified-session-mean

Comment: Thank you. However, I have already logged as root user using ``su`` command and I can do many su command besides ``rabbitmqctl``. I have searched some articles about the problem ``Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session`` but most of them is can not logged as root user.

Answer (score 0):

The `rabbitmq` user account created by the RabbitMQ package doesn't have a password.

You need to run `rabbitmqctl` and `rabbitmq-plugins` as root. `rabbitmqctl` wants to switch to the `rabbitmq` user for most operations, using su(1). Running it as root won't ask for any password.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have already logged as root user using ``su`` command and I can do many su command besides ``rabbitmqctl``.

Comment: Ok, so you are already logged in as root, perfect. Could you please post the exact `rabbitmqctl` command line you use?

Comment: I only input ``rabbitmqctl`` command. No matter what paramaters I have inputed it will alway appear password line.

Comment: Could you please try to run (as root) `sh -x $(which rabbitmqctl) list_queues` and post the output?